# Access rejected by local host in freeradius

Tags: linux, freeradius, radius, aaa-security-protocol

I am no able to execute the radtest command and i cant figure out what the issue it i keep getting the error :

```
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=82, length=20
```

here is the execution:

```
 rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=75, length=20
root@localhost:/etc/freeradius# radtest testing password 127.0.0.1 0 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 82 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "testing"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.0.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=82, length=20
```

here is the debug output:

```
+group authorize {
++[preprocess] = ok
++policy rewrite_calling_station_id {
+++? if (Calling-Station-Id =~ /([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:.]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:.]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})/i)
    (Attribute Calling-Station-Id was not found)
? Evaluating (Calling-Station-Id =~ /([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:.]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:.]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})/i) -> FALSE
+++? if (Calling-Station-Id =~ /([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:.]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:.]?([0-9a-f]{2})[-:]?([0-9a-f]{2})/i) -> FALSE
+++else else {
++++[noop] = noop
+++} # else else = noop
++} # policy rewrite_calling_station_id = noop
[authorized_macs]   expand: %{Calling-Station-ID} -> 
++[authorized_macs] = noop
++? if (!ok)
? Evaluating !(ok) -> TRUE
++? if (!ok) -> TRUE
++if (!ok) {
+++[reject] = reject
++} # if (!ok) = reject
+} # group authorize = reject
Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
# Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
+group REJECT {
[eap] Request didn't contain an EAP-Message, not inserting EAP-Failure
++[eap] = noop
[attr_filter.access_reject]     expand: %{User-Name} -> testing
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
++[attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
+} # group REJECT = updated
Delaying reject of request 2 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Sending delayed reject for request 2
Sending Access-Reject of id 82 to 127.0.0.1 port 55664
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
Cleaning up request 2 ID 82 with timestamp +269
Ready to process requests.
```

this is my users:

```
 testing Cleartext-Password := "password"
```